# add_rewrite_rule is not fired

Tags: url-rewriting, 404-error, rewrite-rules

I need to rewrite some urls:

I have a page (id = 61), with slug `anunciantes` on wich I use a custom template to generate a `wp_query` to list a custom post_type.

I need to be able to filter by two different taxonomies, `area` and `category`

```
function rewrite_rules() { 
    /* Tried:
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    */
    add_rewrite_rule('^/?anunciantes/(.*)/(.*)/$',
                '/anunciantes/?area=$matches[1]&category=$matches[2]',
                'top'); 
   /* Also tried:
   add_rewrite_rule('^/?anunciantes/(.*)/(.*)/$',
                'index.php?page_id=61&area=$matches[1]&category=$matches[2]',
                'top'); 
   */
}
add_action('init', 'rewrite_rules');
```

But I allways get 404 error if I try:

`/anunciantes/one/two/`

( I did go to wp-admin -> permalinks -> save changes , I understand it flushes the rewrite rules? )

So, any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try a plugin for rewrite rules debug, for example [Monkeyman Rewrite Analyzer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/), and see what's going on.

Comment: Did you register your custom query string vars? Read the **Important** bit in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Example)